# Image resize - value cannot be null

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone

Ok, so here's what I've got:

Few lines of code, which get chosen/taken photo and upload it to my server:

```
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        image1.Source = bmp;
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = bmp;
        var largest = Math.Max(bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);
        var ratio = largest / 1024;
        var width = bitmapImage.PixelWidth / ratio;
        var height = bitmapImage.PixelHeight / ratio;
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);
        Stream str = null; 
        wb.SaveJpeg(str, width, height, 0, 75);

        byte[] sbytedata = ReadToEnd(str);
        string s = EncodeTo64(sbytedata.ToString());
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        Uri u = new Uri("//something ;)//");
        wc.OpenWriteCompleted+=new OpenWriteCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenWriteCompleted);
        wc.OpenWriteAsync(u, "POST", sbytedata);
```

And.. it's not working: [exception - screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDTbE.png)

Also, you man need ReadToEnd() function. Here is is:

```
    public static byte[] ReadToEnd(System.IO.Stream stream)
{
    long originalPosition = stream.Position;
    stream.Position = 0;

    try
    {
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];

        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(readBuffer, totalBytesRead, readBuffer.Length - totalBytesRead)) > 0)
        {
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

            if (totalBytesRead == readBuffer.Length)
            {
                int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();
                if (nextByte != -1)
                {
                    byte[] temp = new byte[readBuffer.Length * 2];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, temp, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                    Buffer.SetByte(temp, totalBytesRead, (byte)nextByte);
                    readBuffer = temp;
                    totalBytesRead++;
                }
            }
        }

        byte[] buffer = readBuffer;
        if (readBuffer.Length != totalBytesRead)
        {
            buffer = new byte[totalBytesRead];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, totalBytesRead);
        }
        return buffer;
    }
    finally
    {
        stream.Position = originalPosition;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Stream str = null;
```

To:

```
Stream str = new MemoryStream();
```

Remember - the debugger will show the next statement as the one AFTER the statement that caused the exception. so you are actually dying on the statement before the one you see.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears to be saying `Stream str = null;` is wrong and you need to instance it, i.e. SaveToJpeg writes to an existing stream not creates one and writes to it.